# My onclick function runs before making sure all the required fields error messages

Tags: html, mysql

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <h3>¿Requieres el servicio a domicilio?, regístrate y te contactaremos teste 1</h3>
  <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
  <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup {
      background: #fff;
      clear: left;
      font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
    
    .hide {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      left: -1px;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
    }
  </style>

  <iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hide"></iframe>
  <div id="mc_embed_signup"></div>
  <form name="formulario" action="https://sysmaster.azurewebsites.net" method="post" Target="hiddenFrame"></form>
  <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll"></div>
  <!--End mc_embed_signup-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> campo obligatorio</div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-NOMBRE">
          Nombre  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="NOMBRE" id="mce-NOMBRE" required>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-DOMICILIO">
          Domicilio  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="DOMICILIO" id="mce-DOMICILIO" required data-required-message="E-Mail or Username is Required!">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group size1of2 noMargin">
    <label for="mce-TELEFONO">Teléfono </label>
    <input type="text" name="TELEFONO" class="" value="" id="mce-TELEFONO">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">
          Correo Electrónico  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FUENTESERV">¿Cómo se entero de nuestro servicio? </label>
    <select name="FUENTESERV" value="" id="mce-FUENTESERV">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Redes Sociales</option>
      <option value="2">Sitio Web</option>
      <option value="3">Pasando por sucursal</option>
      <option value="4">Recomendación</option>
      <option value="5">Google</option>
      <option value="6">Correo Electrónico</option>
      <option value="7">Ejecutivo Master Exchange</option>
      <option value="8">Cajero en Sucursal*</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-SUCURSAL">* Si eligió sucursal, ¿qué sucursal? </label>
    <select name="SUCURSAL" value="" id="mce-SUCURSAL">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Plaza La Isla</option>
      <option value="2">Coba</option>
      <option value="3">Plaza de Toros</option>
      <option value="4">Constituyentes</option>
      <option value="5">38 Norte</option>
      <option value="6">10 Norte</option>
      <option value="7">Quinta Avenida</option>
      <option value="8">Hotel El Tesoro</option>
      <option value="9">Plaza Las Californias</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group clearRight">
    <label for="mce-ACTIVIDAD">Actividad a la que se dedica </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="ACTIVIDAD" class="" id="mce-ACTIVIDAD">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group size1of2" id="exchangeNumber">
    <label for="mce-IMPORTE">
          Importe a Cambiar  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
    <div class="icon">$</div><input type="number" name="IMPORTE" value="" id="mce-IMPORTE" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" required>
    <div for="mce-IMPORTE" class="mce_inline_error"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group paddingRight" id="exchangeNumber">
    <label for="mce-DIVISAORIG">&nbsp;</label>
    <select required name="DIVISAORIG" value="" id="mce-DIVISAORIG">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Dólares</option>
      <option value="2">Pesos Mexicanos</option>
      <option value="3">Éuros</option>
      <option value="4">Dólares Canadienses</option>
      <option value="5">Libras</option>
      <option value="6">Francos Suizos</option>
      <option value="7">Reales</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-DIVISACONV">¿A que divisa? </label>
    <select required value="" name="DIVISACONV" id="mce-DIVISACONV">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Euros</option>
      <option value="2">Pesos Mexicanos</option>
      <option value="3">Dólares</option>
      <option value="4">Dólares Canadienses</option>
      <option value="5">Libras</option>
      <option value="6">Francos Suizos</option>
      <option value="7">Reales</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
    <strong>
          Tipo de Operación  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </strong>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="TIPOOPERAC" id="mce-TIPOOPERAC-0" required><label for="mce-TIPOOPERAC-0">Efectivo</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" value="2" name="TIPOOPERAC" id="mce-TIPOOPERAC-1"><label for="mce-TIPOOPERAC-1">Terminal Bancaria</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FRECOPERA">Frecuencia de sus Operaciones<span class="asterisk">*</span> </label>
    <select required name="FRECOPERA" value="" id="mce-FRECOPERA">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Única Ocasión</option>
      <option value="2">Una vez a la semana</option>
      <option value="3">Varias veces por semana</option>
      <option value="4">Una vez al mes</option>
      <option value="5">Varias veces al mes</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="mergeRow-gdpr" class="mergeRow gdpr-mergeRow content__gdprBlock mc-field-group clearRight" style="height: auto!important;im;">
    <div class="content__gdpr">
      <fieldset class="mc_fieldset gdprRequired mc-field-group" name="interestgroup_field" style="height: auto!important;im;">
        <div style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap"><label class="checkbox subfield" for="gdpr_25937"><input type="checkbox" id="gdpr_25937" name="gdpr[25937]" value="Y" class="av-checkbox gdpr" checked required><span style="margin-left: 13px;position: relative;top: -2px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Acepto los</span><a href="https://www.masterexchange.com.mx/aviso-privacidad/" target="_blank" style="position:relative;z-index:2;top: -2px;"> Términos y condiciones</a></label>          </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="content__gdprLegal">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="response h2" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
  <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_f170f86fe3efc4b04ed952511_58d5f3235e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
  <div class="clear">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" onclick="Enviado()">
    <script>
      function Enviado() {
        alert("Solicitud Enviada")
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to valide the required fields before the submit and the onclick fuctions to run, not inbeetweens, but if you fill the `<select>` options, then it runs the onclick function, and submit the incomplete info, i need to make sure I have all the info I ask and marked as `required` before allowing to submit and run the onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **form** tag instead of **div** and for form submission, use **onsubmit** event.
Example

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" required name="text">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```